# Regarding an isometric drawing of a circle, how does this align perfectly?

Tags: geometry, circles, projection

[image: Isometric view of circle]

In the above image, the circle is drawn as an isometric view. Why does it align well when we draw a six-pointed star? The radius of the larger arc is thrice the radius of the smaller arc. My question is, why does this $3:1$ ratio of radii work? Any other ratio won't work obviously (intuitively), but the reason? Why exactly this star-shaped construction?

Comment: How exactly you are projecting - from a point or parallel?

Comment: @Moti Parallel...

Comment: In that case ratios of areas are maintained and as result certain direction ratios are maintained while certain directions the ratio will be 1.